# Sequelize many to many relation filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, many-to-many

so I need to get trips with crossing point of certain ID but also with all crossing points.

My current model:

```
const Trip = sequelize.define("trips", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
        allowNull: false,
    },
});
```

Crossing Point

```
const Municipality = sequelize.define("municipalities", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: false,
    },
});

const crossingPoint = sequelize.define("crossing_points",{
    id:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
        allowNull: true
    },
})
```

Relationships

```
db.trip.belongsToMany(db.municipality, {
    through: {
        model: db.crossingPoint,
        unique: false,
    }
});

db.municipality.belongsToMany(db.trip,{
    through: {
        model: db.crossingPoint,
        unique: false,
    }
});
```

Currently my findAll code looks like this

```
const trips = Trip.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Municipality,
            through: { attributes: ["description"] },
            attributes: ["id", "name"],
            where: { id: id },
            required: true
        },
    ],
});
```

but that obviously finds all trips which have crossing point of certain id, but I also need to include all crosing points of the trip.

Current output whe id is 65

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Trip 1",
    "createdAt": "2023-02-20T15:42:24.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-02-20T15:42:24.000Z",
    "municipalities": [
        {
            "id": 65,
            "name": "Štěpánov"
        }
    ]
}
```

Output I want

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Trip 1",
    "createdAt": "2023-02-20T15:42:24.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-02-20T15:42:24.000Z",
    "municipalities": [
        {
            "id": 365,
            "name": "Krňany"
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "name": "Štěpánov"
        },
        {
            "id": 366,
            "name": "Chlum (Strakonice)"
        }
    ]
}
```

All trips which has crossing point id 65 with all other crossing points

Comment: Could you add CrossingPoint model definition? it says Crossing Point for 2nd table but you are showing Municipality definition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i added crossing point model to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `IN` query with subqueries.

We want to generate a query that fetches all `tripId` that associated with `municipalityId` = 65, then query `Trip` and `Municipality` that contains the fetched `tripId`.

Unfortunately, there is no high level support on subqueries in Sequelize, we need to use low level `queryGenerator` interface.

```
// Subquery options to fetch distinct tripId from CrossingPoint
// *tripId, municipalityId can be different based on your DB or configs. Check your CrossingPoint table in DB.
const options = {
  attributes: [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('tripId'))],
  where: {
    municipalityId: 65
  }
};

// Generate select subquery statement
const subQuery = db.sequelize.getQueryInterface()
                   .queryGenerator
                   .selectQuery('crossing_points', options, CrossingPoint)
                   .slice(0, -1); // This is to remove semicolon(;)
```

Then use the subquery in `IN` statement.

```
const trips = await Trip.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Op.in]: Sequelize.literal(`(${subQuery})`)
    }
  },
  include: {
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    model: Municipality,
    through: {
      attributes: []
    },
    required: true
  }
});
```