# Sequelize - Return the entire model with a where query on submodel

Tags: sequelize.js

Using Sequelize, I have a model named Users, and a submodel named Address.

The model named Address has two columns "location" and "type"

I want to return all the Users that location of type office, but I want to return ALL their addresses.

Will not work:

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

const Address = sequelize.define('Address', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  location: Sequelize.STRING,
  type: Sequelize.STRING
});
User.hasMany(Address, { as: 'Addresses' }); // add alias to association
Address.belongsTo(User, { as: 'user' }); // add alias to association

const users = await User.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Address,
      where: {
        type: 'office'
      },
      required: true
    }
  ]
});
```

The above will only return the address of the office, but I need ALL the addresses for this User.

Comment: does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75696914/sequelize-many-to-many-relation-filtering/75723218#75723218

this question is using `belongsToMany` association but can apply to `hasMany` as well

Comment: Thanks! @Emma - using sub query is certainly an option. in fact that's how I got it done eventually. but I was hoping that there's a better way to do it.